# Dockerfile fatal error: jni.h: No such file or directory

Tags: go, gcc, dockerfile, java-native-interface

I am trying to dockerize a Go application which uses a Go Java JNI library (https://github.com/timob/jnigi) and getting an error on the build stage as follows:

> /go/src/github.com/timob/jnigi/cinit.go:8:9: fatal error: jni.h: No such file or directory 
> 8 | #include<jni.h>
> |^~~~~~~
>  compilation terminated.

My Dockerfile:

```
FROM golang:alpine as BUILD

ENV GO111MODULE=auto

RUN apk update && \
    apk upgrade && \
    apk add git && \
    apk add unzip && \ 
    apk add openssl-dev && \
    apk add build-base && \
    apk add --no-cache gcc musl-dev && \
    apk add --no-cache openjdk8-jre

COPY . /go/src/project
WORKDIR /go/src/project

RUN go get -d -v

RUN CGO_ENABLED=1 GOOS=linux GOARCH=amd64 go build -a -installsuffix cgo -o /go/dist/app

FROM alpine:latest AS FINAL

COPY --from=BUILD /go/dist/app /project-runtime/app

RUN apk update && \
    apk add tzdata && \
    apk add apr && \
    apk add ca-certificates && rm -rf /var/cache/apk/* \
    apk add openssl

RUN update-ca-certificates

WORKDIR /project-runtime

ENTRYPOINT ["./app"]
```

The error happens when the "RUN CGO_ENABLED=1 GOOS=linux GOARCH=amd64 go build -a -installsuffix cgo -o /go/dist/app" is executed. How should I add the jni.h file? Could you please help me?

Comment: you have to install `jdk` instead of `jre`. It should be just `add --no-cache openjdk8` as far as I recall.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing to place this script in the JDK root path `https://github.com/timob/jnigi/blob/master/compilevars.sh` according to [these](https://github.com/timob/jnigi#compile) instructions.

```
The CGO_CFLAGS needs to be set to add the JNI C header files. The compilevars.sh script will do this.

# put this in your build script
source <gopath>/src/tekao.net/jnigi/compilevars.sh <root path of jdk>
```